# JSON data revceiving PHP

Tags: php, json

The server receives from URL post string as below:

```
{
    "head": {
        "comm": 7,
        "compress": false,
        "ms": 1451029423348,
        "encrypt": false,
        "version": 2
    },
    "body": {
        "data1": 0,
        "data2": 59,
        "data3": -40,
        "data4": 0,
        "data5": 0,
    }
}
```

I have PHP file as below need  to receive JSON format data from URL or java app sending post to server. Using server PHP ver 5.4.45, I can't change it.

```
$json = file_get_contents('php://input'); 
$string = get_magic_quotes_gpc() ? stripslashes($json) : $json;
$object = json_decode($string);
var_dump($object);
```

then i want to put to array each item in to array into $data variable each fields into $data array

I always receiving NULL , What can be the problem ?

Comment: what is the result of $json? Does it fetch the requested data?

Comment: What is the value of `$string` before is decoded?

Comment: do you want to use using POST?

Comment: Ehsan Razm khah, Yes data sent by post from URL for test, in real life JSON data comes from TCP 


AdamJeffers $string before decode is the JSON data on top of question coming from URL or TCP Port       .

DS9 Result of $json  is NULL

Answer (score 4):

If I paste your json here: http://jsonlint.com/ it gives a "Error: Parse error on line 14:"

Maybe it helps when you remove the comma after `"data5": 0,`

Comment: I forgot to remove the comma, the list was up to data20, I cut at data5 to make the question shorter.

Answer (score 0):

The JSON data is not correct. Try after removing the `,` after `"data": 0`.
Correct JSON :

```
{
  "head": {
      "comm": 7,
      "compress": false,
      "ms": 1451029423348,
      "encrypt": false,
      "version": 2
  },
  "body": {
      "data1": 0,
      "data2": 59,
      "data3": -40,
      "data4": 0,
      "data5": 0
  }
}
```

Comment: I forgot to remove the comma, the list was up to data20, I cut at data5 to make the question shorter.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$json = file_get_contents('php://input'); 
$string = get_magic_quotes_gpc() ? stripslashes($json) : $json;
$object = json_decode($string);
```

By using foreach function walk thru `object` elements and typecast them as an array

```
 foreach($object as $k=>$v){
        $data[$k] = (array)$v;
    }
```

and the result will be as follows:

```
    Array
(
    [head] => Array
        (
            [comm] => 7
            [compress] => 
            [ms] => 1451029423348
            [encrypt] => 
            [version] => 2
        )

    [body] => Array
        (
            [data1] => 0
            [data2] => 59
            [data3] => -40
            [data4] => 0
            [data5] => 0
        )

)
```

Comment: Please add some explanation.

Comment: Now You can click the green outlined checkmark to the left of the answer that solved your problem. This marks the answer as "accepted".

Answer (score 0):

If, as you say, `$json` is `NULL`, the comma after `"data5"` is only because of text that was cut to make pasted code shorter, and you're using  PHP <5.6 then according to http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php it could only be that either:

- you're reading `php://input` multiple times (if not you then maybe a framework you're using or whatever);
- the sender is passing data to you as `multipart/form-data`, which `php://input` cannot read.